# Which FILTER_SANITIZE_* function for $_GET

Tags: php, sanitization

I need to sanitize data that is coming from an `$_GET` variable, but I'm not sure which one to use from the list

- `FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED`
- `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`
- `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`

This is my case:

I'm building a request handler class which should return variables from `$_GET` and `$_POST`. This values will be used in other classes

Here is what I have done so far (*Still rough draft*)

```
class RequestHandler
{
    protected $getRequest;
    protected $postRequest;
    protected $cookieRequest;
    protected $sessionRequest;

    public function __construct($getRequest = null, $postRequest = null, $cookieRequest = null, $sessionRequest = null)
    {
        if ($getRequest)
            $this->setGetRequest($getRequest);

        if ($postRequest)   
            $this->setPostRequest($postRequest);

        if ($cookieRequest)
            $this->setCookieRequest($cookieRequest);

        if ($sessionRequest)    
            $this->setSessionRequest($sessionRequest);
    }

    public function setGetRequest($getRequest)
    {
        $this->getRequest = $getRequest;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setPostRequest($postRequest)
    {
        $this->postRequest = $postRequest;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCookieRequest($cookieRequest)
    {
        $this->cookieRequest = $cookieRequest;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setSessionRequest($sessionRequest)
    {
        $this->sessionRequest = $sessionRequest;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGetRequest()
    {
        return $this->getRequest;
    }

    public function getPostRequest()
    {
        return $this->postRequest;
    }

    public function getCookieRequest()
    {
        return $this->cookieRequest;
    }

    public function getSessionRequest()
    {
        return $this->sessionRequest;
    }

}
```

I can then use the class like

```
$a = new RequestHandler($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION);
```

Where should I do this sanitation, in my setter or in my constructor

Comment: *but I'm not sure which one to use from the list* Why not use all of them :D?  *in my setter or in my constructor* I think that doesn't matter to much, but to keep the constructor a bit more cleaner i would put them in the setters, (or even better vvv This comment below me)

Comment: Generally speaking: Don't sanitise, escape, and do it when you output the data not when receive it.

Comment: You should definitely do the sanitation in your class constructor. What kind of data do  you have to manage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing a generic class to get data from an HTTP request.

There is no sane way to sanitise it.

To make data safe you need to consider two things (and you can't know either of them when writing a generic class for pulling data from an HTTP request):

## What the data is supposed to be

Is the data supposed to be someone's date of birth? Then you need to check that it is a valid date.

Is the data supposed to be someone's address? Then you [need to be very careful about what you think is allowed](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).

Is the data supposed to be raw HTML? If you plan on putting it in an HTML document then you have all sorts of risk and you need to think about how much you trust the person sending the data and/or using something like HTML Purifier to limit which tags and attributes can be used.

Is the data supposed to be plain text? Well, it might include characters like `<` and `'` which have special meaning in various places (HTML and SQL for example) and they might be used entirely legitimately in the context of whatever the text is talking about. You can't filter them out entirely without breaking what people are trying to say.

Most of the time, you will want to either:

- Allow a *very* narrow set of input *or*
- Put no restrictions on input

## Where the data is going

Usually, you make data safe by escaping it. How you escape it depends on where you put it.

With SQL, you would generally use a prepared statement with placeholders. With XML, you would generally use a DOM library. With HTML you would usually use `htmlspecialchars()`. And so on.

---

In short:

- Don't focus on securing/filtering data as it comes into your program.
- Do your filtering at the point in your program where you know what the data is supposed to be.
- Deal with security risks just before you move the data from PHP to some other language or format.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, the data will mostly be search terms and integer values :-)